# How to filter values based on multiple inputs in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Hi I have started working on a project in which i need to select the best prospect proxies for the underlying(s) based on the following hierarchy

1. Sector
2. Region (CCY)

My idea is for example if we are looking to find a suitable proxy for the UL AAPL.OQ (sector : **IT**, Industry Group : **Technology Hardware**, Indusry : **Technology Hardware**, Region (ccy) :  **USD**

the tool should filter out the information from the entire universe saved in csv based on the parameters given as input - like sector, sub sector and region (as given below in the screenshot - filtered out the list of suitable proxies). if we can do the same in python ? also how can we achieve this for multiple underlyings at the same time ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\samuel\\Desktop\\Sector.csv')
df.columns = ['RIC','Sector','Industry Group','Sub Industry', 'SOLA SECTOR', 'CCY']
print(df)


filter_data = int(input('select sector: '))
filter_data = int(input('select region: '))

filtered=(df.loc[df['sector'] == filter_data])
indexdata = filtered.set_index(' ')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for multiple selection, you can just :

```
sector = int(input('select sector: '))
region = int(input('select region: '))


filtered=(df.loc[(df['sector'] == sector) &(df['region'] == region)])
```

Comment: Thanks skaddd for helping out, can you please check the snap i have uploaded

Comment: You want to reproduce the selection you did using the sorftware? e. g. selecting `CCV =='USD'` and so on?

Comment: i want to do the selection based on the user input, using spyder as software